# How can I add 4TB SATA disk to motherboard without formatting ?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, gpt, usb-3

I had a `4TB seagate USB3.0` hard drive with data.

I took the case out and got the internal SATA drive from that case.

Then I joined it to my [Intel D975XBX2 motherboard](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d975xbx2/sb/CS-029346.htm) with SATA cables, but the system only detected the drive `256GB`, with the rest unallocated.

The data was not important so I converted it to a GPT disk and then the board detects it as full `4TB storage`.

Now I have another disk like that which I **don't want to reformat**.

Is there a way to make my motherboard detect the entire partition, or convert to GPT without formatting?

Comment: What OS are you running? Would copying the data out and copying it back in be an option? I wasn't even aware that mbr supports 4tb, so how it was formatted and it 'worked' is a bit of a mystery to me, but more information would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be positive, but I believe that what you want to do will be very difficult. The reason is that many external disk enclosures translate the 512-byte logical sector size used by most modern hard disks into 4096-byte sectors (grouping eight 512-byte sectors into one 4096-byte sector). When you remove the disk from the external enclosure, your partition table therefore becomes worthless. The result can be all sorts of weird issues with the disk size appearing wrong or the disk seeming to be unpartitioned, or to have strange partitions that make no sense.

If I'm right, then the only way to get this to work is to examine your partition table while the disk is in its external enclosure and compute the equivalent partition start and end point(s) for once the disk is accessed "naked." You can then create a new partition table using these values. This is, however, ***extremely*** risky. I only advise this sort of thing if you've backed up all your data -- and with that done, it's not that much harder to simply wipe the disk clean and restore the backup. Also, this isn't the sort of operation that's easy to do on a routine basis, so if you plan to move the disk back and forth between its external enclosure and use without it, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can Convert MBR to GPT without data loss by the means of GPT fdisk tool, which is free and open at sourceforge.
This is the list of features:

Features

```
Edit GUID partition table (GPT) definitions in Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS X, or Windows
Convert MBR to GPT without data loss
Convert BSD disklabels to GPT without data loss
Create hybrid MBR or convert GPT to MBR without data loss
Repair damaged GPT data structures
Repair damaged MBR data structures (FixParts)
```

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/index.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Link only answers are a *horrible* thing to do since if your links go down, your answers are useless. You may want to talk about what these tools are and what they do.

Comment: I don't think the problem is fundamentally one of MBR-to-GPT conversion, although that might be a minor part of the solution -- see my answer for what I suspect is going on.

Comment: @RodSmith: And the funniest part of this answer is that these links point to your own site :)